# bitfield in ternary operations as lvalue

Tags: c++

I recently encountered a tricky/interesting issue by combining ternary operators 
with bitfield access, the code has been simplified enough to expose just the problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union
{
    struct 
    {
        uint32_t    Bit_0_1     : 2;
        uint32_t    Bit_2       : 1;
        uint32_t    Bit_3_To_31 : 29;
    } BitField;
    uint32_t RawValue;
} UnnamedUnion;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UnnamedUnion a;
    UnnamedUnion b;
    a.RawValue = 0;
    b.RawValue = 0;
    //Version 1. Works
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        a.BitField.Bit_0_1 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        b.BitField.Bit_0_1 = 0;
    }
    printf("Reg value : %u\n", a.RawValue);
    //Version 2. Also works
    (1 == 1 ? a.RawValue : b.RawValue) = 1;
    printf("Reg value : %u\n", a.RawValue);
    //Version 3. Crashes!
    (1 == 1 ? a.BitField.Bit_0_1 : b.BitField.Bit_0_1) = 2;
    printf("Reg value : %u\n", a.RawValue);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that version 1, 2, 3 are all equivalent expressions. I have my assumptions about how this
happened as I never worked on compilers, but would like to hear what everyone thinks!  
**Update** : Confirmed to fail in both VS 2012 & 2013 
**Update** : Code was edited again to really just focus on the issue alone. (no casting anymore)

Comment: I suppose you are using VC, what version exactly? I tried gcc and clang with your code, no crashes, prints 0,1,2.

Comment: Looks like (particularly with your second update that eliminates the possible aliasing red herring) you've uncovered a codegen bug in MSVC.  You should open a bug report on connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks for the awesome insight. A ticket has been submitted : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/962553/codegen-bug-in-accessing-bitfield-in-ternary-operations-as-lvalue

Answer (score 1):

Versions 1 and 3 definitely violate the strict-alias rules, which is undefined behavior. Given that, having version 1 working while version 3 fails is definitely one possible undefined behavior.

I *believe* version 2 is also undefined but I can't quite recall if a union is allowed to alias its active member's type, so it might be perfectly well-defined (either way your code working is a valid outcome).

Given that, it doesn't make a lot of sense to try to guess why one compiler, with one set of compiler options, and one set of standard libraries, on one particular piece of hardware may choose one specific set of undefined behavior to implement.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with strict aliasing rule, try this code below : UnnamedUnion obj; (1 == 1 ? obj.BitField.Bit_0_1 : obj.BitField.Bit_0_1) = 2; It still fails with the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
reinterpret_cast<UnnamedUnion&>(someArray[(1==1)?0:1]).RawValue = 1;
```

Which, given the nature of `C++` booleans, could even be simplified to simply:

```
reinterpret_cast<UnnamedUnion&>(someArray[(1!=1)]).RawValue = 1;
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it would merely provide more information.  It should be a comment.